# OnionShare index? Something like The Pirate Bay (description and preview)

Tags: bittorrent

Quote from [GitHub OnionShare](https://github.com/micahflee/onionshare/wiki)

> Open OnionShare and drag and drop files and folders you wish to share,
>   and click Start Sharing. It will show you a .onion URL such as
>   `http://asxmi4q6i7pajg2b.onion/egg-cain` and copy it to your clipboard.
>   This is the secret URL that can be used to download the file you're
>   sharing. If you'd like multiple people to be able to download this
>   file, uncheck the "close automatically" checkbox.

Is OnionShare something like an "anonymous" BitTorrent? Are there indexes / trackers with descriptions and previews? Something like the Pirate Bay is? URI?

Lots of Torrents get deleted because of DMCA, so I would assume that OnionShare doesn't delete DMCA files?

Or do I misunderstand OnionShare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onionshare is a decentralized file hoster, so it's something in between file hosters (like mega) and bitorrent.

It's decentralized, so anyone can install Onionshare, and run it : it will create an Hidden service where you can send files anonymously through the Tor Network. But, you'll be the only "seeder", and if you shut down the application, the files won't be available anymore, because they're from a unique source. So don't wait for great downloading speed like torrents.

As the identity of the hoster remains anonymous, I don't thinks DMCA files are effective.

Official website :

https://onionshare.org/

Github repos :

https://github.com/micahflee/onionshare

Answer (score 3):

OnionShare isn't like BitTorrent, it's not a filesharing network.

It's a bit of software that does two things:

1. It creates an onion service.
2. It starts a web server that shares your chosen files over the onion service.

There are no indexes of onion services or onionshare instances, they're distributed manually to the intended recipients of the shared files.

It would be possible to create a place for people to share onionshare links but they are intended to be temporary shares, so it's not the intended use case.

As with all onion services there is no central authority which can arbitrarily censor content, so content would be hard to censor.

Comment: Though could you use Tor without the Onion Share / Proxy property? I understand that it's one of the main appeals for Tor, though I wrote a question the issue: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14650/turning-off-the-proxy-part-of-tor