# Turning off the proxy part of Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, network-configuration, proxy

I would like to use the tor browser but without the Proxy / Onion element of it. The reason why I would like to do this is because I'd like to use Tor as my main go to browser for normal activities and I have more trust in Tor than in Google Chrome or Mozilla regarding sending private information back from the browser itself (AKA application-level privacy/security).

**QUESTION:** How can I disable the Proxy part of tor WITHOUT disabling the rest of the security features Tor has?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR:**

______**[** ATTEMPT# **1]**______

Open Menu **>** Add-ons **>** Extensions **>** Disable TorLauncher

After doing this and trying to go on any random URL, I get the following error message:

> The proxy server is refusing connections
>
> Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections.
>
> - Check the proxy settings to make sure that they are correct.
> - Contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working.

*[IMPORTANT NOTE] I already did try disabling the Torbutton add-on as well, and the same error happened. HOWEVER I do not want to disable the Torbutton add-on since it provides important application-level security, which I would like to keep. I just tried disabling it to see if it was causing some indirect issues.*

______**[** ATTEMPT# **2]**______

Open Menu **>** Options **>** Advanced **>** Network **>**  Settings **>** Selecting "No proxy"

This was done together with keeping **TorLauncher** disabled. Now I get the following error:

> Unable to find the proxy server
>
> Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that can't be found.
>
> - Check the proxy settings to make sure that they are correct.
> - Check to make sure your computer has a working network connection.
> - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Tor Browser is permitted to access the Web.

So it seems that the browser is still looking for a proxy server to connect to, even after I disabled that option in the Network Settings.

I have been trying to find something else that might get the job done, but without success. I am still looking. Would anyone happen to know the solution?

Comment: also see [How to dissconnect Tor browser from the Tor network](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10367/how-to-dissconnect-tor-browser-from-the-tor-network/10383#10383)

Comment: thank you for the feedback @canonizingironize and everyone else with the links to the sources! It was very helpful!